# Store and Retrieve DSA public and private keys in mysql

Tags: java, mysql

I have to use DSA (Digital Signature Algorithm) in my project, implementing using Java.I have a problem that I can't store the public and private key of DSA (of type PublicKey & PrivateKey). When I stored it as a blob, can't retrieve to its form (ie., PublicKey). Can anyone help me?

```
KeyPairGenerator pairgen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("DSA");
SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
pairgen.initialize(KEYSIZE, random);
KeyPair keyPair = pairgen.generateKeyPair();
PublicKey pu=keyPair.getPublic();
```

I have to store this up and have to retrieve

Comment: what's the problem with `varchar`

Comment: Data too long for column when using varchar

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. 1) How to store as `PublicKey` outside Java runtime? *(hint: as bytes)* 2) How to get `byte[]` from `PublicKey`? 3) How to save `byte[]` in your database? 4) How to load `byte[]` from your database? 5) How to get `PublicKey` from `byte[]`? Those are the steps, so please edit question and ask the **specific** question on which part is troubling you. Or better yet, search for it online, once you've made it more clear in your head what exactly it is you're looking for.

Comment: if publickey is stored in byte[] form,how can i convert it into PublicKey type.It can be retrieved as byte or converted to string.But it is not possible to convert into a PublicKey type.  Object pu=keyPair.getPublic(); PublicKey pk=(PublicKey)pu; it is also fine.So i tried to store pu as object,and retrieved as object :  Object obj=(Object)rs.getObject("pu");
               PublicKey p=(PublicKey)obj; But it didnt work,cannot convert string to PublcKey .

Answer (score 0):

Store it as `byte[]` using `pu.getEncoded()`.

To restore into PublicKey object you load the byte array and make the following call

```
KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("DSA");
PublicKey pu = kf.generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes));
```

Optionally you can also encode it with base64.